# Drop DataFrame Row Based on Existing Condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, shift, isin

Given the following pandas `df` -

| **Holding Account** | **Account Type** | **Column A** | **Column B** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rupert 06 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1825973 | 1702598 |
| Rupert 07 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1697870 | 1825973 |
| - | - | - | - |
| Caroline 06 (0131465) | Holding Account | 11112222 | 5435450 |
| Caroline 07 (0131465) | Holding Account | 7896545 | 11112222 |

I had been trying to find a way to do the following -

- Step 1 - For the entire `df`, search for instances of Column B values appearing in Column A
  (example: Column B of `Caroline 07` == Column A of `Caroline 06`)
- Step 2 - Rows that meet the above criteria should have there Column B value changed to the Column B value of the row who they matches
  (example: `Caroline 7` Column B value will change from `11112222` to `5435450`

This means the pandas `df` will now look as follows -

| **Holding Account** | **Account Type** | **Column A** | **Column B** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rupert 06 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1825973 | 1702598 |
| Rupert 07 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1697870 | **1702598** |
| - | - | - | - |
| Caroline 06 (0131465) | Holding Account | 11112222 | 5435450 |
| Caroline 07 (0131465) | Holding Account | 7896545 | **5435450** |

**Code to achieve this:** the following code achieves Steps 1 & 2 -

```
import numpy as np
df['Column B'] = np.where(df['Column B'].isin(df['Column A'].values),df['Column B'].shift(),df['Column B'])
```

**Where I need help:** I would like to expand the code, to include the following:

- Step 3 - Delete the row whose Column A value matched the other row's Column B, once Step 2 is complete
  (example: `Rupert 06 (23938996)` and `Caroline 06 (0131465)` would be deleted, as they received Column B values from `Rupert 07 (23938996)` and `Caroline 07 (0131465)`.

| **Holding Account** | **Account Type** | **Column A** | **Column B** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rupert 07 (23938996) | Holding Account | 1697870 | **1702598** |
| Caroline 07 (0131465) | Holding Account | 7896545 | **5435450** |

Does anyone know how I can expand the code appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `np.where`, just compute some masks:

```
rows_to_remove = df['Column A'].isin(df['Column B'])
df.loc[df['Column B'].isin(df['Column A'].values), 'Column B'] = df.loc[rows_to_remove, 'Column B'].to_numpy()
df = df[~rows_to_remove]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Holding Account     Account Type  Column A  Column B
1   Rupert 07 (23938996)  Holding Account   1697870   1702598
3  Caroline 07 (0131465)  Holding Account   7896545   5435450
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think you've defined `rows_to_remove` variable?

Comment: Thanks @richardec, I'm incredibly grateful for your support.